# F# Type mismatch on curried functions

Tags: f#

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following FSharp/F# code:

```
module File1

let api a =
    printf ("VALUE = %A") a

let router ops =
    [|
       api (ops (fun (list, _) -> list()))
       api (ops (fun (_, get) -> get 1))
    |]

let withContext ops handler =
    let context = "CONTEXT"
    handler (ops context)

let operations context =
    printf ("CONTEXT = %s") context

    let list () = [|1;2;3|]
    let get id = "Test"
    (list, get)

let setup() =
    let ops = withContext operations
    router ops
```

Results in the following error

```
Results in the following compation error
Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a
    ((unit -> int []) * (int -> int []) -> int []) -> 'a    
but given a
    ((unit -> int []) * (int -> string) -> 'b) -> 'b    
The type 'int []' does not match the type 'string'
```

I know the problem is that ops function has been bound to return a int[] but I want to be able to also return a string.

I think I'm missing a trick with some generic declarations but after hours of moving code around I can’t seem to work it out.

*(I've simplified the code to highlight my problem)*

Comment: Just a few remarks: ``[| ... |]`` is an array and ``[ ... ]`` is a list. ``api`` should be `` 'T -> unit``, right? So ``router ops`` should be ``unit []``, an array of units. Is that what you want?

Comment: How to make many types into 1 type? Discriminated unions. ``type OpKinds = | Array of int -> int [] | String of int -> string``

Comment: This will be part of a suave.io application so the return types could be any number so I'm not sure trying to make huge list of discriminated unions will work.

Comment: Thanks to bitticklerand and @paweł-jasiurkowski for helping. I think I'll end up going with the following code for now:

    [|
       ops (fun (list, _) -> list() :> obj) |> api
       ops (fun (_, get) -> get 1 :> obj) |> api
    |]

Cast result then send it to the api

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `ops` needs to have a return type of its `handler` resolved at compilation, and you want to return different types base on some run-time logic.

It is basically an equivalent of:

```
let fun1 switch arg2 arg3 =
  if switch then
     arg2
  else
     arg3
```

and you want to run it this way:

```
fun1 true 1 "string"
```

Of course, arg2 and arg3 need to have the same type, so it won't work

What you can do is to run "api" function on a handler result, before returning it (so it will always the same type - unit).

```
let router ops =
    [|
        ops (fun (list, _) -> api <| list()))
        ops (fun (_, get) -> api <| get 1))
    |]
```

Alternatively, you could return objects of discriminated union type (then you will need some more logic in api function).

(Technically, you could also return `obj`).

**Bonus**

You don't need the array of units to be returned in a `router` function, returning one unit is just fine:

```
let router ops =
    ops (fun (list, _) -> api <| list()))
    ops (fun (_, get) -> api <| get 1))
```

In this way, `setup` function will also return `unit` and you will be able to run it without a need to run `ignore` on the result to get rid of `This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'unit[]'` warning.

Comment: The switch will require knowing all different return types and could end up as a large monolithic function

Comment: Moving the api function means that everything is now bound to a unit, this compiles but doesn't solve the problem. If I was to expend out the example the ops function will connect to the database, run a query then dispose of the connection, the result of that will then be serialized by api

Comment: @davidtme If I understand what you want to do correctly, my tip would be to look up "type providers" and how to build them. F# is statically typed language and as such, you cannot invent new types at run time (depending on the definition of a database table, for example). To create the illusion of doing that, type providers were invented.

Comment: Still, this part:

(ops (fun (list, _) -> **list()**))

 will need to return always the same type.

It can be discriminated union, interface, base class, System.Object, or anything else that helps you return actually different types under one label.

Comment: The object could be an option - list() :> obj and get 1 :> obj seem to work and api just deals with objects - let api (a:obj)

Comment: Also, moving the api function means that everything is now bound to a return type of the api function, so exactly the same as it was before moving the api function.

Comment: @PawełJasiurkowski thanks for the comment but the in the real world api wrap the value in a http context and async (and suave.io web part) moving that function would mean ops (the data layer) would need to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard for me to understand, but I think the basic issue is that you want `withContext` to have a "rank 2" type (so that the universal quantification of the type variable `'b` can happen after the application of the first argument).  In F#, this can be accomplished by creating a new type with a generic method and using that:

```
let api a =
    printf ("VALUE = %A") a

type Handler<'a> = abstract Handle<'b> : f:('a->'b) -> 'b

let router (ops:Handler<_>) =
    [|
       api (ops.Handle (fun (list, _) -> list()))
       api (ops.Handle (fun (_, get) -> get 1))
    |]
let withContext ops =
    let context = "CONTEXT"
    { new Handler<_> with member __.Handle f = f (ops context) }

let operations context =
    printf ("CONTEXT = %s") context

    let list () = [|1;2;3|]
    let get id = "Test"
    (list, get)

let setup() =
    let ops = withContext operations
    router ops
```

Comment: I really like this approach, it means nothing has to be cast to an obj